# I am facing issue at time of installation of cakephp on Ubuntu 14.* pl check attached image

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing issue at time of installation of cakephp on Ubuntu 14.* pl check attached image

[image]

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much tells you what the problem is and what to do.

On your system the the mbstring PHP extension is not installed or is not enabled.

You need to find out how to install the PHP mbstring extension on your Ubuntu box or how to enable it if it is already installed.